# Error when using update_attributes with multiple nested items in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models with a `has_many :through` join model, like so:

```
class Brief < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :brief_product_benefits
  has_many :product_benefits, through: :brief_product_benefits

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :brief_product_benefits, :allow_destroy => true

  ...
end


class ProductBenefit < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :brief_product_benefits
  has_many :briefs, through: :brief_product_benefits

end

class BriefProductBenefit < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :brief
  belongs_to :product_benefit

end
```

I'm getting a strange error when I try to update multiple `BriefProductBenefit` objects at the same time through `@brief.update_attributes`. Here are the results I'm getting:

Assuming I fetch a record like so:

```
brief = Brief.find(1)
```

Successful create (inserts two new records):

```
brief_params = {"brief_product_benefits_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"", "product_benefit_id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"", "product_benefit_id"=>"2"}]}
brief.update_attributes(brief_params)

-> INSERT INTO "brief_product_benefits" ("brief_id", "product_benefit_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["brief_id", 2], ["product_benefit_id", 1], ["created_at", 2016-07-13 07:33:54 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-07-13 07:33:54 UTC]]
-> INSERT INTO "brief_product_benefits" ("brief_id", "product_benefit_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["brief_id", 2], ["product_benefit_id", 2], ["created_at", 2016-07-13 07:33:54 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-07-13 07:33:54 UTC]]
```

Successful update (updates `product_benefit_id`):

```
brief_params = {"brief_product_benefits_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"3", "product_benefit_id"=>"2"}]}
brief.update_attributes(brief_params)

-> UPDATE "brief_product_benefits" SET "product_benefit_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "brief_product_benefits"."id" = $3  [["product_benefit_id", 2], ["updated_at", 2016-07-13 07:35:10 UTC], ["id", 3]]
```

Successful delete (removes `BriefProductBenefit` with id of 3):

```
brief_params = {"brief_product_benefits_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"3", "product_benefit_id"=>"2", "_destroy":true}]}
brief.update_attributes(brief_params)

-> DELETE FROM "brief_product_benefits" WHERE "brief_product_benefits"."id" = $1  [["id", 3]]
```

Failed update when sending an array of nested objects:

```
brief_params = {"brief_product_benefits_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"2", "product_benefit_id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"3", "product_benefit_id"=>"1"}]}
brief.update_attributes(brief_params)

-> (0.1ms)  BEGIN
-> (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

And then I get the following stack trace:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:12:in `visit'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/postgres_ext-3.0.0/lib/postgres_ext/arel/4.1/visitors/postgresql.rb:22:in `block in visit_Array'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/postgres_ext-3.0.0/lib/postgres_ext/arel/4.1/visitors/postgresql.rb:22:in `map'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/postgres_ext-3.0.0/lib/postgres_ext/arel/4.1/visitors/postgresql.rb:22:in `visit_Array'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13:in `visit'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:641:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_In'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/determine_if_preparable_visitor.rb:13:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_In'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13:in `visit'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:808:in `block in inject_join'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:806:in `each'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:806:in `each_with_index'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:806:in `each'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:806:in `inject'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:806:in `inject_join'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:657:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_And'
from /Users/holiday/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/arel-7.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/reduce.rb:13:in `visit'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here but with simple operations like Post.where(id: [1,2,3])
Rails 5 too, same Arel version, same reduce.rb line

EDIT: Fixed by removing gem 'postgres_ext', apparently it doesnt yet have support for rails 5